# In-app purchase warning message

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have the following warning after creation of new in-app product in itunes connect.
What this warning mean? Can I start testing in-app purchase inside my app?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to test it yes. But you won't be able to publish the app on the App Store.